# Multisite foreach loop returning only one result

Tags: loop, multisite

I have a subdir multisite setup of 10 sites where I have maintained similar Url structure in all of them for a custom post like `partoftheurl-in-country` (except mainsite) and for the mainsite it's  `partoftheurl` only. So far so good, everything works fine.

Now I need to create a custom function that returns an array of all matching urls for the current url across the network. I have done this but returns any one of the site only! can anyone put a flash where I'm going wrong.

```
 function rel_alternate_network(){
    global $post;
    $slugX = is_main_site() ? $post->post_name : rtrim($post->post_name, '-in-'.strtolower(do_shortcode('[country]')));
    $urls = array();
    foreach(get_sites() as $site){
        if( $site->blog_id == get_current_blog_id()) {continue;}
            switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);
            $slugY = get_post_by_slug($slugX);
            $urls['site'] = $site->path;
            $urls['slug'] = $slugY->post_name;
            restore_current_blog();
    }
    return $urls;
}
```

Note: `get_post_by_slug()` is custom function I created that works perfectly alright; there is also a shortcode `[country]` created that returns the country name in the url.

Comment: Is it only returning the site you're currently on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pass through the `foreach()` loop, you're wiping out the values that are already in your `$urls` array.

Try something like this:

```
 function rel_alternate_network(){
    global $post;
    $slugX = is_main_site() ? $post->post_name : rtrim($post->post_name, '-in-'.strtolower(do_shortcode('[country]')));
    $urls = array();
    foreach(get_sites() as $site){
        if( $site->blog_id == get_current_blog_id()) {continue;}
            switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);
            $slugY = get_post_by_slug($slugX);
            $new_url['site'] = $site->path;
            $new_url['slug'] = $slugY->post_name;
            $urls[] = $new_url; // Adds the new URL to the URLs array.
            restore_current_blog();
    }
    return $urls;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pat. I realized the same thing just after posting it here :-)